# C# how to Read 1st line, then second line, then third, in a loop with sendkeys?

Tags: c#

I wanna create a programm that sendkeys from a multiline textbox to external programm.
In the textbox are multiply lines of text, but i need the 1st line,
and sendkeys it over to an external programm.

the idea is, to do it in a loop and it stops when it hits the last line.

I have made some code but it doesnt work like I need to, im not the best in this type of programming language.

Text in Multiline textbox:

```
Hello im here 
Here to create 
Create for honor 
honor for all 
all for hello 
Hello im here 
Here to create 
Create for honor 
honor for all 
all for hello
```

Code:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Countdown of 5 seconds before the SendKeys starts sending.
        timer1.Start();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
            for (int i = 0; i < richTextBox1.Lines.Length; i++)
        { 
            SendKeys.Send( richTextBox1.Lines[i] + "\r\n"); 
            // First line 
            // Start timer1 agian to read second line.
            //
        }
        // Loop ends when it hits the last line (Bottom).
}
```

Whats happens in the following code is not exactly what I need,
it will send the whole text at once in seperated lines..
Like This:

```
Hello im here

Here to create

Create for honor

honor for all

all for hello

Hello im here

Here to create

Create for honor

honor for all

all for hello
```

But i need it like this:

```
Hello im here 
//first line -> Timer1 ends -> Start Timer1 agian to read second line
Here to create
//Second line -> Timer1 ends -> Start Timer1 agian to read third line
Create for honor
//Third line -> Timer1 ends -> Start Timer1 agian to read fourth line
```

Etc. Etc. Till the loop hits the last line and stops by the last line.

Answer (score 2):

Your timer isn't actually doing anything, as you're sleeping using `Thread.Sleep` instead of waiting for the timer event - so you sleep once for 5s at the start, then never again.

Just change your code to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < richTextBox1.Lines.Length; i++)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
    SendKeys.Send(richTextBox1.Lines[i] + "\r\n");
}
```

This way, each iteration you'll sleep for 5s before moving on to the next line.

If you're getting multiple newlines as you showed in your example, then check that the `Lines` strings don't already contain a terminating newline character (in which case you're making each string end with two newlines).

---

It might be worth bearing in mind that unless this is happening on the UI thread (not advisable), the user can happily edit the textbox's text while you're doing this. You should either do some UI stuff to stop that, or just take a clone of the `Lines` member at the start of the function and use the copy instead.

Comment: Got it! but how to get only the 1st line? 
I got your code and changed richTextBox1.Lines[i] to richTextBox1.Lines[0] so it will pick only the first line.
It sends the first line! :D 

But there are 117 lines in the textbox and it sends 117x the first line..

How to pick only the first line without that the first line go multiply

Comment: @AlJuicebox You only want to send the first line? That's not what your original question asked for. In that case, just remove your `for` loop and do a `Thread.Sleep` followed by `SendKeys.Send(richTextBox1.Lines[0] + "\r\n");`.

Comment: I got it working. Excuse me that I didn't asked that in first place..
I did `for (int i = 0; i < richTextBox1.Lines.Length; i++)` to `for (int i = 117; i < richTextBox1.Lines.Length; i++)` and by the sendkeys i did `SendKeys.Send(richTextBox1.Lines[0] + "\n");`. Now it only picks the first line.